# LunarVim How to move tabs using tabmove command

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

I'm trying to move my tabs with `tabmove -` but lvim is saying `E475 Invalid argument -`

What might the problem? What should I use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it with `:BufferLineMoveNext` and `:BufferLineMovePrev`

Comment: It works. that's really odd for vim user.